# Liquibase where clause with sub query

Tags: liquibase

Is it possible to write sub query in liquibase without using the `<sql>` tag

Lets say we have the following tables:

```
Table Cars:
  CarID      int
  CarName    nvarchar(100)

Table Drivers:
  DriverID   int
  DriverName nvarchar(100)

Table CarDrivers:
  CarID      int
  DriverID   int
```

Example

```
<delete tableName="CarDrivers">
    <where>DriverID in select driver.DriverID from Drivers driver where driver.DriverName = 'John Doe'</where>
</delete>
```

Is it possible to compute such subquery as `select driver.DriverID from Drivers driver where driver.DriverName = 'John Doe'` inside a liquibase `<where>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try like this:

```
<delete tableName="CarDrivers">
    <where>driverId IN (SELECT driverId FROM Drivers WHERE driverName IN ('John', 'Jack'))</where>
</delete>
```